# Unit testing the login method with firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, unit-testing

I'm carrying out a university project. I need to know if the unit test I did of the login method with firebase in android studio is correct. I'm a beginner with unit testing. Below I indicate the method and the test carried out.

```
public void signUp(String nickname, String email, String password,String dataOfBirth, String gender){
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        referenceDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

                            UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
                            User currUser = new User(uid, nickname, email, password, dataOfBirth, gender);

                            referenceDb.child("Users").child(uid).setValue(currUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                       Toast.makeText(singUp_fragment.getActivity(), "SingUp successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        openHomeFragment();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(singUp_fragment.getActivity(), "SingUp failed. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        singUp_fragment.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Resources resources = singUp_fragment.getStartActivity().getResources();
                            singUp_fragment.cleanTextInputErrors();
                            try {
                                throw task.getException();
                            } catch (NoInternetConnectionException e) {
                                MotionToast.display(
                                        singUp_fragment.getStartActivity(),
                                        R.string.toast_warning_internet_connection,
                                        MotionToastType.WARNING_MOTION_TOAST
                                );
                            } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException e) {
                                singUp_fragment.setTextInputNicknameError(
                                        resources.getString(R.string.fragment_sign_up_invalid_nickname)
                                );
                            } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                                singUp_fragment.setTextInputEmailError(
                                        resources.getString(R.string.fragment_sign_up_invalid_login)
                                );
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                MotionToast.display(
                                        singUp_fragment.getStartActivity(),
                                        R.string.toast_error_unknown_error,
                                        MotionToastType.ERROR_MOTION_TOAST
                                );
                            }
                        }
                        singUp_fragment.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        singUp_fragment.setEnabledButtonSignUp(true);
                    }
                });
    }
```

I tested it like this:

```
public class SingIn_Test {
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    boolean test;

    @Test
    public void ValidEmailPasswordTest(){

        test = false;
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("annal@live.it", "Annamaria2222").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Assert.assertTrue(true);

                } else {
                    Assert.assertFalse(false);
                }
                test = true;
            }
        });
        while(!test){

        }
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void InvalidEmptyEmailPasswordTest(){

        test = false;
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("", "").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Assert.assertTrue(true);

                } else {
                    Assert.assertFalse(false);
                }
                test = true;
            }
        });
        while(!test){

        }
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void InvalidEmptyEmailTest(){

        test = false;
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("", "Annamaria2222").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Assert.assertTrue(true);

                } else {
                    Assert.assertFalse(false);
                }
                test = true;
            }
        });
        while(!test){

        }
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void InvalidEmptyPasswordTest(){

        test = false;
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("annal@live.it", "").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Assert.assertTrue(true);

                } else {
                    Assert.assertFalse(false);
                }
                test = true;
            }
        });
        while(!test){

        }
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void InvalidFormatEmailPasswordTest(){

        test = false;
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("annal@live", "Annamaria").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Assert.assertTrue(true);

                } else {
                    Assert.assertFalse(false);
                }
                test = true;
            }
        });
        while(!test){

        }
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void InvalidFormatPasswordTest(){

        test = false;
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("annal@live.it", "Annamaria").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Assert.assertTrue(true);

                } else {
                    Assert.assertFalse(false);
                }
                test = true;
            }
        });
        while(!test){

        }
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void InvalidFormatEmailTest(){

        test = false;
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("annal@live", "Annamaria2222").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Assert.assertTrue(true);

                } else {
                    Assert.assertFalse(false);
                }
                test = true;
            }
        });
        while(!test){

        }
    }

}
```

it's correct?